# Return Future value from a function

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I recently started to learn Rust and I'm not sure how I can return future value from a function that should return a Result. When I try to return just the response variable and remove the Result output, I get an error: **cannot use the `?` operator in a function that returns `std::string::String`**

```
#[tokio::main]
async fn download() -> Result<(),reqwest::Error> {
    let url = "https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v8/finance/chart/TSLA";
    let response = reqwest::get(url)
                            .await?
                            .text()
                            .await?;
    Ok(response)
 }
```

What I expect in main() is to get and print the response value:

```
fn main() {
    let response = download();
    println!("{:?}", response)
}
```

Comment: An `async` function, which you can introduce by writing `async fn` instead of fn, does nothing other than to return a `Future` when called. This `Future` is a suspended computation which you can drive to completion by `.awaiting` it.

Comment: a fine resource to understand `async` programming is https://rust-lang.github.io/async-book/01_getting_started/01_chapter.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose your code should looks something like this

```rust
extern crate tokio; // 0.2.13

async fn download() -> Result<String, reqwest::Error> {
    let url = "https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v8/finance/chart/TSLA";

    reqwest::get(url).await?.text().await
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let response = download().await;

    println!("{:?}", response)
}
```

Here is [rust playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=50bfcff2ee576b9e476770638f78e1f5)